# creating a chart using ng2-charts and giving it the labels from a observable

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

currently I am figuring out how to get Labels pushed when using ng2-charts.

But the following only leads to that under the Y-Axis the labels are shown. But i want an label for each data point.

The Data is of String Format (Better would be Date but this does'nt work somehow) as i want to display dates and data.

```
  data: Data[]
  constructor(
  private route: ActivatedRoute,
  private coolService: CoolService,
  private location: Location,
  ) { }
  lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [];
  lineChartLabels: Label[] = [];
lineChartOptions = {
  responsive: true,
};
lineChartColors: Color[] = [
  { borderColor: 'black', backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,0,0.28)' },
];
lineChartLegend = true;
lineChartPlugins = [];
lineChartType = 'line';

  getData(): void{
  const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.coolService.getData(id).subscribe(
    response => {
      this.data = response;
      this.lineChartData.push({
        data: response.map(item => item.cool_speed),
        label: 'Some name for the line lol'
        });
        this.lineChartLabels.push({label: response.map(item => item.date)});
    },
    error => { }
  );
  }
```

[How it looks at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQXo2.png)

Maybe someone has some expirience using this as im new.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1st possible solution:

I think this line here is your problem.

```js
this.lineChartLabels.push({label: response.map(item => item.date)});
```

You're pushing one object label for multiple data points, instead of multiple string labels. There should be one label for each of the points in `lineChartData[0].data`. That's why it's just mapping the first point and you have a straight line. The length of `lineChartLabels` should correspond to the length of `lineChartData[0].data`,
etc. To fix it try:

```js
this.lineChartLabels.push(response.map(item => item.date));
```

#### 2nd possible solution

Here's the solution on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-line-chart).

```js
  public lineChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [], label: 'Series A' },
  ];

  public lineChartLabels: Label[] = [];

  
  constructor(private coolService: CoolService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.coolService.getData().subscribe({
      next: coolItems => {
        coolItems.forEach(ci => {
          this.lineChartData[0].data.push(ci.coolData);
          this.lineChartLabels.push(ci.date);
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: first of all thanks for bein interested in my question. Tried your fix, but it still looks the same. Even made my db data only return 12 Lines (maybe could be that it's simply to much data but thats not the issue here).

Comment: Would you mind posting a dummy sample of your data to the question @dejanero ? I'd like to know how it's structured to better understand the issue you're having.

Comment: Yeah Sorry my bad. @the_coops `[{"id": 1, "cool_data": 12.32,"date": Thu 01 Jan 2004 00:00:00 GMT},{the same again},{...}]` Is what it is structured like.

Comment: @dejanero I've added a new solution with a live example

Comment: Currently it does not display any data at me. But this is something i need to figure out somehow as your example is working. Thank you @the_coops :) Edit: it works !

Comment: That's great news @dejanero. Happy it worked out for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right you want a graph with one value `cool_data` by date like I can see it in your example below:

```json
[{"id": 1, "cool_data": 12.32,"date": Thu 01 Jan 2004 00:00:00 GMT},{the same again},{...}]
```

So you don’t have to use labels.

You can use the [Time Cartesian Axis](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html).

Data is structured like that:

```json
data: [{
     t: new Date(),
     y: 1
}, {
    t: new Date(),
    y: 10
}]
```

So, you just have to map your own data: `date` to `t` (easy ^^ ) and `cool_data` to `y` (easy too).

Something like the following (don’t copy/paste, I didn’t test that code):

```js
getData(): void{
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
        this.coolService.getData(id).subscribe(
        response => {
            this.data = response;
            this.lineChartData.push({
                data: response.map(item => {y: item.cool_speed, t: item.date}),
                label: 'Some name for the line lol'
                ...
```

And maybe you’ll have to do a `new Date(item.date)` or to use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/).